# Unable to access the self created storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a storage account, however, unable to access it. Error showing access denied.

The steps I have followed to create the storage account:

1. [image]
2. [image]

The error I'm getting is:

[image]

This is how the firewall and virtual network is looking like from the portal.Is there any specific things I need to select here? If I need to do some extra selection - how can I understand the meaning of that?

Also, blob storage is not appearing, do I need to select "premium" for blob storage?

I don't see any network setting now from the Azure portal.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any step by step method with good explanation to create a storage account?

Also,I'm unable to see blob storage.

The connectivity check is showing me error:

> Failed to list containers: authMode: 4
>   code: AuthorizationFailure
>   content: _CYCLIC_OBJECT_
>   message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>   RequestId:cce36eae-901e-001e-0472-415a25000000
>   Time:2020-06-13T11:02:14.4850017Z
>   name: StorageError
>   requestId: cce36eae-901e-001e-0472-415a25000000
>   url: https://example.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&_=1592046134245
>   xhr: {}
>
> Failed to list queues: authMode: 4
>   code: AuthorizationFailure
>   content: _CYCLIC_OBJECT_
>   message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>   RequestId:9c699d17-4003-0050-3672-4174ad000000
>   Time:2020-06-13T11:02:13.5044983Z
>   name: StorageError
>   requestId: 9c699d17-4003-0050-3672-4174ad000000
>   url: https://exmaple.queue.core.windows.net/?comp=list&_=1592046133224
>   xhr: {}
>
> Failed to list containers: authMode: 1
>   code: AuthorizationFailure
>   content: _CYCLIC_OBJECT_
>   message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>   RequestId:a5b1514f-e01e-0066-2e72-41f9dd000000
>   Time:2020-06-13T11:02:14.7298198Z
>   name: StorageError
>   requestId: a5b1514f-e01e-0066-2e72-41f9dd000000
>   url: https://example.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&_=1592046134491&sv=2019-10-10&ss=bqtf&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacuptfx&se=2020-06-13T19:02:13Z&sig=E4jZb9I6BjWBTrIzMnD9keq1BU8UfI%2F%2BZA1820lt3qk%3D
>   xhr: {}

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the access issue, please allow your client IP address to access the storage account.

[image]

Comment: Add IP ranges to allow access from the internet or your on-premises networks. - Could you please little elaborate? I think, after adding this IP, this will be only accessible from this IP address not from other IP..right? How can I make sure, any other trusted IPs are able to access this?

Comment: That’s partially correct. In this case your storage account will be accessible from your IP address and all other private IP addresses you’ve configured.

Comment: If I'm selecting allow all network. It looks like its working. That mean, who ever, will be having my Key can access to my storage. Also, one more question, I don't see blob, is it due to my storage account is basic now and to see blob, i need to go for premium ?

Comment: `That mean, who ever, will be having my Key can access to my storage` - That's correct. `Also, one more question, I don't see blob, is it due to my storage account is basic now and to see blob, i need to go for premium ?` - You should be able to see blobs based on your storage account kind (General Purpose V2). Do you see `Blob service` in the left hand pane (above Queue service)?

Comment: Thank you for clue. Do you see Blob service in the left hand pane (above Queue service) - No, that is my main worry...

Comment: That's totally weird. Can you share a screenshot of the left hand pane? Please see the screenshot that I shared in my answer.